# play video with flowplayer and JQuery when the mouse pointer is over a link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, flowplayer

I need to play videos (with flowplayer) when the mouse is over a link. I tried to do it myself but I could not. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You should provide code and show what you have tried when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is handle the hover event and then play the video using the flowplayer api.  You have not specified which flowplayer you are using (HTML or flash), so I will provide an example for both.

**HTML example**

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    // plays the video on hover
    flowplayer().play();
}, function(){
    // stops the video on hover out
    flowplayer().stop();
});
```

**Flash example**

```
$f("player", "flowplayer.swf", "my-video.flv");

$('a').hover(function(){
    // plays the video on hover
    $f().play();
}, function(){
    // stops the video on hover out
    $f().stop();
});
```